# older telemaster lens and nikon D3300 body

Tags: lens-mount

I have a Swift telemaster model 841 lens.... it has an adapter with it but the adapter won't quite fit the Nikon D3300 body.  Is there another adapter ring that I can get so I can use my Telemaster lens?  Any info would be appreciated greatly.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the Swift Telemaster 841 spotting scope with your Nikon camera, you will need a 841PA Photo Adapter and a T-mount to Nikon adapter.

[841PA Photo Adapter](http://www.birdcentral.com/index.php?c=21&p=481)

[image]

[T-Mount SLR Camera Adapter for Nikon F-Mount](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/252747-REG/Meade_07378_T_Mount_SLR_Camera_Adapter.html)

[image]